# How to fix Interface and type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I try to write component, that should get data with diferent variable names from api and render ut. I have two response with same data but with diferent variable names for example:

```
FirstReq {
    id          number
    published   boolean
    publishDate string
    newsImage   string
    newsTitle   string
}

SecondReq {
    archived     boolean
    id           number
    artImage     string
    postingDate  string
    articleTitle string
}
```

After I got data, I tried to assign recived data with diferend variable names to unified object but think I did it wrong and got TS errors. Component code:

```
interface ItemInterface {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  date?: string,
  image?: string,
}

type Item = ItemInterface[]

const Items: React.FC = () => {
  const [itemsData, setItems] = useState<Item>()

  useEffect(() => {
    Http.get<Item>(url).then((res: Item) => setListItems(res))
  }, [])

  if (typeof (itemsData) !== 'undefined') {
    const unifiedItem: Item = {
      id: itemsData.id, // TS error -  TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Item'
      title: itemsData.newsTitle || itemsData.articleTitle, // same ERR
      date: itemsData.publishDate || itemsData.postingDate,
      image: itemsData.newsImage || itemsData.artImage,
    }
  }

  const itemsList = () => {
    if (typeof (itemsData) !== 'undefined') {
      return unifiedItem.map((item:{
        id:number, title:string, image?:string
      }) => {
        return (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <ItemPreview item={item} />
          </li>
        );
      })
    }
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }

  return (
      <ul>
        {itemsList()}
      </ul>
  )
}

export default Items
```

main Question is how I can asign recived data to unified object "unifiedItem"?

Comment: So `itemsData`, if defined, is an *array*.  You have to get the `id`, `title`, and `image` props from one of the *elements* of the array, like `itemsData[0].id`.  As for `anotherTitle` I'm not sure what to tell you; it's not in your type.  What are you trying to accomplish specifically?

Comment: you are trying to access the items like a property on an object so either try `itemData['id']`  or make the object not an array.   you should also change `const [itemsData, setItems] = useState<Item>()`  to `const [itemsData, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([])`

Comment: @jcalz I get data from API and variable names can be diferent, as I wrote in question, and I try to unifie this date - assign it to "unifiedItem"

Comment: Then you need a separate type or interface for the thing coming from your API. Can you explain why you are treating an array as if it were one of the elements in the array?  Or let me rephrase my "what are you trying to accomplish" question: are you getting an *array* of things back from your API?  Or a *single* thing?  If it's the former, do you want an *array* of `unifiedItem`?  Or a randomly picked one?  Or what?  The code as written doesn't make it clear enough to constitute a [mcve] (at least not one I can figure out)/  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Your type `Item` is defined as an `ItemInterface` array. You can't retrieve an id from an entire array, you have to specified an index in order to retrive an `ItemInterface` typed element.

For example : `itemsData[0].id` should not throw any error !

Comment: other variables like "anotherTitle" throw errors, I think I just did it all wrong way...